# html5videoplayer - control bar - missing or double display

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm using html5videoplayer 6.2.14 in a typo3 6.1.7 installation. The control bar doesn't appear as it should - either missing or double display (because the mouseover text like "play" appears with the image, mouseover text doesn't show up).

The plugin parameters are set to autoplay and show control bar.

http://www.alexianer-berlin-hedwigkliniken.de/index.php?id=5674

How can I correct this?

This is the code without control bar:

```
<div id="video_4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-paused" width="680" height="385" style="width: 680px; height: 385px;"> 
    <video id="video_4_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{"techOrder":["youtube","vimeo","html5","flash"], "ytcontrols": true}" autoplay="" preload="auto"> 
    </video> 
</div>
```

And that's the code with double control bar:

```
<video id="video_4_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{"techOrder":["youtube","vimeo","html5","flash"], "ytcontrols": true}" autoplay="" preload="auto" src="....webm"> 
<div class="vjs-control-bar"> 
<div class="vjs-play-control vjs-control vjs-playing" role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0"> 
<div class="vjs-control-content"> 
    <span class="vjs-control-text">Pause</span> 
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to S.O. ! The community here loves code : give them code (of what you tried so far) so they can help you :)

Comment: This is the code without control bar: 
<div id="video_4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-paused" width="680" height="385" style="width: 680px; height: 385px;">
            <video id="video_4_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{"techOrder":["youtube","vimeo","html5","flash"], "ytcontrols": true}" autoplay="" preload="auto"> </video>
    </div>

Comment: And that's the code with double control bar:
...
<video id="video_4_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{"techOrder":["youtube","vimeo","html5","flash"], "ytcontrols": true}" autoplay="" preload="auto" src="....webm">
...
<div class="vjs-control-bar">
<div class="vjs-play-control vjs-control vjs-playing" role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0">
<div class="vjs-control-content">
<span class="vjs-control-text">Pause</span>
</div>
</div>
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading two different versions of video.js's javascript and css, and they're conflicting.

v4.9.0:

```
<link href="typo3conf/ext/html5videoplayer/Resources/Public/video-js-4.9.0/video-js.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="typo3conf/ext/html5videoplayer/Resources/Public/video-js-4.9.0/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

v3.2.0:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

You should remove the old version.

Comment: Did it! Thank you very much again - As I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't know the process - but I'm willing to learn it, so thanks again for the accept hint!!!